# Why are vedic chants used to propitiate puranic deities?

Tags: belief, practice, vedic-gods, vedic-chanting

Sama Veda for instance mostly has hymns to Indra, Agni, and Varuna, and yet we use these very hymns nowadays to worship Ganesha, Skanda, Shiva, and others. Where is the scriptural basis for doing so?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at:  [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: Please edit your question. As it is now, asking for 'Why' is asking for opinions.

Comment: Now what's next? : "*Why is Shiva called MahAdeva?*" - this should also be closed as "Opinion - Based", because it's using the word 'why' &. 'why' is an opinion incitement!!

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda may I know for every word "why" means its opinion based?

Comment: I'm confused :) How should I have asked this question?